# spimi algorithm misunderstanding

Tags: c++, algorithm, dictionary, indexing, information-retrieval

I'm trying to implement a single-pass in-memory indexer in C++

But in the algorithm, I think there is something wrong or ( most probably) I have misunderstanding

```
SPIMI-INVERT(token_stream)
  output_file = NEWFILE() 
  dictionary = NEWHASH() 

  while (free memory available) 
     token ← next(token_stream)
     if term(token) ∈ dictionary
        then postings_list = ADDTODICTIONARY(dictionary, term(token)) 
        else postings_list=GETPOSTINGSLIST(dictionary,term(token))
     if full(postings_list)
        then postings_list = DOUBLEPOSTINGSLIST(dictionary, term(token))

     ADDTOPOSTINGSLIST(postings_list, docID(token)) 
  sorted_terms ← SORTTERMS(dictionary)  
  WRITEBLOCKTODISK(sorted_terms,dictionary,output_file) 
  return output_file
```

Let's assume that I did all parsings and turned all the documents into a stream of **tokens** where **tokens** are *`term,doc_id`* pairs

http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/single-pass-in-memory-indexing-1.html says that SPIMI-INVERT function is called for every block.

Alright let's start then,

- we read the stream block by block, so now I have one single block and
  sent it over SPIMI-INVERT function as an argument
- the function does some processing with the token for the dictionary

> somehow ( maybe because the dictionary is too big) we don't have free
>   memory anymore when we are in the while loop.

- The algorithm breaks the loop and writes the current dictionary to
  disk.

> But from outside world (as a caller of the function) I have no idea if
>   the block that I send it as an argument processed totally or not. Don't you
>   think that there is something wrong here?

Comment: You've transcribed the algorithm incorrectly; ``ADDTOPOSTINGSLIST()`` should be inside the loop, not outside.  If I'm understanding this correctly, you'd call this procedure repeatedly until the entire token_stream is consumed, each call producing one file on disk.  You'd then merge those files together (basically, one pass of the mergesort algorithm).

Comment: yes you are right I corrected it. Yes I will call this procedure for every single block. And we will have the same number of  files as blocks. And merge them. So far everything is ok. But I am asking that what happens if we don't have any memory in the while loop? or why do they put there a condition "free memory available" instead of just True?

Comment: You don't call this "for every single block"; you call it to PRODUCE a block, the size of which depends on how much room you have in memory.  I'm not sure this is a really suitable algorithm for modern operating systems, as "free memory available" is not a well-defined limit - you can always get more in the form of virtual memory, but it gets slower and slower as you go.

Comment: in the linked page, on the second sentence says "writes each block's dictionary to disk, and then starts a new dictionary for the next block." I don't think that it creates a block. If it would be the case, I think that calling this procedure repeatedly would be meaningless..( Actually, you can not do that because how can you know where the previous procedure left)

Comment: You know where the previous procedure left off by the amount of the token_stream that has been consumed.

Comment: Okay, I gave an amount of toke stream to the procedure, but because lack of memory it could not process the whole stream, but just half of it. As a caller how can I know if it is the situation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because no answer so far and after talking to my professor, I am answering my question.

I must say that the algorithm is not really clear, because my professor was not sure too. And I am answering this question like how I interpreted it.

> token stream is a file that includes tokens(term , doc-id pair)

```
while (there is token in token stream)
      dict = new dictionary()
      while(there is free memory available)
            token = next_token()
            dict.add_to_postingList(token)
      write_dict_to_file(dict)
      delete dict

//Assuming posting list is dynamically sized and dictionary knows if a term exist.
```

[Here](https://github.com/EnesKilicaslan/Single-Pass-in-Memory.git) I implemented it in C++,  might be usefull

Comment: You do not Sort the itens before you write to disk, this is a problem because there is no guarantee that the lexicon will be ordered to merge blocks for the final index.